# Doom Emacs Haskell helper type infer

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I try my hand on Emacs and has a great time developing with Haskell. Below is a feature that is invaluable to me. After writing a function without the type, Doom Emacs automatically infer its type, and when I click on it, it automatically fill the type in.

The thing is, I would like to do it with keyboard binding instead of clicking. But I cannot find the command to bind it. Please help me if you know the command. Many thanks.

[image]